# how to define a type which has for property a function that return string?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to define a type that use a property which contains a function that return a string?
I didn't find anything related to this.

```
type ContextProps = {
  saveToken: (text: string) => void;
  getToken: () => string;
};
```

the getToken function is not happy with it with all theses syntaxes

```
export const TokenContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
  saveToken: (text: string) => {},
  getToken: () => {token: string},
});
```

```
export const TokenContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
  saveToken: (text: string) => {},
  getToken: () => text: string,
});
```

Comment: On type level `getToken: () => {token: string}` defines a function which returns an object. So in your first implementation attempt: `getToken: () => ({token: 'some token'}),`

Comment: Sorry, i've made a mistake, i dont want a function taht return an object, but a function that return a string, i've updated the post i've try this ```export const TokenContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
  saveToken: (text: string) => {},
  getToken: () => (text: string),
});``` but it's still complaining

Comment: OK, so `getToken: () => 'some token'`

Comment: thx a lot! it did work